# How to connect kepware-ua-server in Eclipse Milo

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have a client.der generated by Kepware opc ua configuration.How to use it convert to KeyPair?

```
    File clientFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Rex\\Desktop\\client.der");
    FileInputStream privatekeyfile = new FileInputStream(clientFile);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(privatekeyfile));
    Object object = pemParser.readObject();
    PEMDecryptorProvider pemDecryptorProvider = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(certificate.getPublicKey().toString().toCharArray());
    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
    keyPair = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(pemDecryptorProvider));
```

Object object = pemParser.readObject(); the object always is null.

Comment: How do I extract a private key from a .der file?

Comment: The DER file contains just the certificate, there is no private key. That aside, you should not be trying to use the client key you got from Kepware when connecting to Kepware. Your Milo-based client should have its own certificate.

Comment: thank you so much. it works.you are my hero!!!haha